# Select columns, count(id) from table and reference table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query where I want to fetch columns from two tables (a parent and reference table), as well as select total number of categories of each post on the reference table

articles

```
id
title
poster
pdate
content
```

categories

```
id
name
```

cats_rel (Relationship table with Foreign Key constraints)

```
id
pid
cat_id
```

I want to fetch list of posts with one category id and total number of categories for each post.

I use this to fetch the required data, but it is slow. Is there a better way to get it faster?

```
SELECT cc.id, title, poster, pdate, content, js.pid, js.sno 
FROM articles cc LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT pid, cat_id, count(cat_id) as sno FROM cats_rel GROUP BY pid)js 
ON js.pid = cc.id WHERE cc.status='approved' ORDER BY cc.id DESC
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry for that, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a inner query.

```
SELECT cc.id, title, poster, pdate, content, js.pid, count(js.cat_id) as sno 
FROM articles wp 
LEFT JOIN cats_rel js ON js.pid = cc.id
WHERE wp.status='approved'
group by cc.id, title, poster, pdate, content, js.pid
ORDER BY cc.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the query using a correlated subquery

```
SELECT cc.id, cc.title, cc.poster, cc.pdate, cc.content, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM cats_rel js
        WHERE js.pid = cc.id
       ) as sno 
FROM articles cc
WHERE cc.status = 'approved'
ORDER BY cc.id DESC;
```

(It seems that `js.pid` is redundant in the `select` list.)

For this query, you want two indexes:  `articles(status, id desc)` and `cats_rel(pid)`.

Comment: I want to fetch one category id (js.pid) alongside the total.

Comment: That's nice, but that is not what your question is asking for.  It is fetching `pid`, which is equivalent to `cc.id` when there is a match.